# Xcode 7.1 - iOS Simulator 9.1 doesn't shows copied applications

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am running in a very weird issue after up-grade my Xcode from 6.4 to 7.1. I am using SimpHolder to fetch all iOS simulator devices because I have to copy the application in each devices' "/Container/Builds/Application" folder so that i can launch it on all devices of SDK 9.1 and take screenshots for my project.

But now what happening is when i launch my build app to open it on default device (lets say iPhone 6), i go to its application folder and copy the folder of the application and copy it in other devices (Lets say iPhone 5, as same as i used to do before). But when i switched to other device (iPhone 5) it doesn't show me the copied application. When i was on Xcode 6.4 this trick was working fine.

Here is one more catch, I downloaded SDK 8.4 on Xcode 7.1. And copied the application folder in SDK 8.4 devices (Lets say iPhone 6 Plus), it is working fine i am able to see the application, even able to launch it from simulator.

I don't know what apple has changed again in Xcode 7.1 with SDK 9.1.

Comment: Can you provide any feedback regarding my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very sure, but I assumed that if you moved a pre-built app that was built for *iPhone 5* (Apple A6) or lower device to a newer device's simulator (e.g. iPhone 5s/6), it might work as *iPhone 5s* (Apple A7) and newer support 64 bit processor (which means the simulator is also capable of running `x86_64` instead of just `i386`).

Thus if you moved an app that was built for `64 bit` ARM device to a `32 bit` only simulator, it won't work as it's not recognizable by the `i386` simulator.

As you are using SDK 8.4/9.x, the pre-built app could be either 32 or 64 bit. I doubt the simulator will build them as FAT binary as it's always a debug release in the simulator.

Comment: Let me check with my developer team if this is the issue.

Comment: I tested it and it is fine. It is perfectly opening on "iPhone 6 - 9.1 ios simulator", if i move the installed app in other devices of 9.1. It doesn't show in them.

Comment: Just to be clear, did you move the app from a simulator to another simulator, or to an actual iOS device? The simulator uses x86 architecture, which is not executable on iOS devices as they are ARM.